# How to get complete body content without string truncate?

Tags: c#

Using mailto option in asp.net
Need to define body content. The body content of the mail contains `&`, quote `'`, double quote `"`. While passing the string to body variable, then the string is getting truncated due to the special characters.

So how to get format the complete text without truncate while passing to mailto?

Here cell 0 indicate hyperlink from the gridview and the 3rd parameter picks from the gridview cell (it contains single quote, double quote,etc)

```
((HyperLink)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0]).NavigateUrl = setMail("abc", "Welcome", "Device is showing \"NO APN SPECIFIED ON THE DEVICE\" on a sim card which is \"not-activated\" yet although there are data connection and customer is able to surf the internet with the error message.")

protected String setMail(string owner, string subject, string body)
{               
    string body_text = "Hi%20" + owner + "%0D %0D" + "Information: " + body + "%0D %0D";           

    return String.Format("mailto:{0}?subject={1}&body={2}", owner, subject, body_text);
}
```

Comment: Where is your code buddy?

Comment: string owner = "abc";
            string subject = "Welcome";
            string body = "Device is showing \"NO APN SPECIFIED ON THE DEVICE\" on a sim card which is \"not-activated\" yet although there are data connection and customer is able to surf the internet with the error message.";

            String.Format("mailto:{0}?subject={1}&body={2}", owner,
                                subject,                                
                                body)

Comment: above is an example

Comment: @Sahana Add your code in question

Comment: You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41698189/edit) your question by clicking [the edit button](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41698189/edit). This code exemple must be a part of your question.  It has no value as comment.

Comment: You have not provided a complete question. You have not shown how you are passing the code to the mailto attribute. You need to show that code in your question. If you aren't sure what to include in a question, please refer to [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i edited question and added source code. pls help me

Answer (score -2):

You should add @ character at the beginning of set value

```
string stringvar = @"//\'sometext";
```

Comment: And that is helpful, how?